# Che cosa significa "tentare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Nichel* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Per quella roccia senza pace provavo un affetto fragile e precario: con essa avevo contratto un duplice legame, prima nelle imprese con Sandro, poi qui, **tentandola** come chimico per strapparle il tesoro.

Non capisco cosa significa che Levi "tentava" la roccia come chimico. Ho letto tutte le accezioni della voce "tentare" sul  [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tentare) e sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000902.jpg)], [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000903.jpg)] e [[3](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000904.jpg)]), ma non riesco a vedere a quale possa corrispondere l'uso che se ne fa nel testo. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Per dare un po' più di contesto, dovete sapere che in questo racconto, Levi parla del suo lavoro appena laureato in chimica in un laboratorio situato in una miniera d'amianto, in cui deve estrarre il nichel dal materiale di scarto.

Comment: Forse *saggiandola*? Ci vorrebbe un chimico.

Comment: @egreg Esatto, siamo alla definizione 9 delle pagine linkate: "studiare, analizzare"

Comment: Sì, @RiccardoDeContardi: ha perfettamente senso nel contesto del racconto.

Comment: Altra definizione di tentare è toccare, tastare per esplorare, riconoscere, saggiare qualcosa: *tentammo le assi per vedere se ci reggevano.* https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/tentare.html